# Doctrine: A new entity was found through the relationship странное поведение

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Видел что на stackoverflow много подобных вопросов, но не видел ни одного рабочего решения. Ситуации возникновения у всех разные, тем не менее приведу свою проблему.

У меня работает парсер XML фида, большого, выглядит так:

```php
public function run(): void
    {
        $this->runParameters->entityManager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

        $filePath = '/tmp/guzzle-downloadGLOgDf';
        //$filePath = $this->downloader->downloadXMLFeed($this->runParameters->feedLink);
        $reader = new FeedReader($filePath);

        $countOffers = 0;
        foreach ($reader->read() as $item) {

            if (!$this->runParameters->entityManager->isOpen()) {
                $this->runParameters->entityManager = $this->runParameters->entityManager->create(
                    $this->runParameters->entityManager->getConnection(),
                    $this->runParameters->entityManager->getConfiguration()
                );
            }

            //$this->runParameters->entityManager->beginTransaction();

            try {
                $parser = new Parser\Wrapper($item, $this->runParameters);
                $countOffers += $parser->parse();
                //$this->runParameters->entityManager->commit();
            } catch (\Throwable $t) {
                //$this->runParameters->entityManager->rollback();
                $this->runParameters->logger->error('Failed parsed offer', [
                    'code' => $t->getCode(),
                    'message' => $t->getMessage(),
                    'file' => $t->getFile(),
                    'line' => $t->getLine(),
                    'trace' => $t->getTraceAsString(),
                ]);
            }

            $this->runParameters->entityManager->clear();
            //$this->runParameters->entityManager->close();
        }

        $this->runParameters->logger->info('Handled ' . $countOffers . ' offers');
    }
```

Из кода видно, что я пытался использовать решения с пересозанием соединения, с его закрытием, с его очисткой и множество других способов, написанных здесь на stackoverflow.

Однако, ошибка все равно возникает, не смотря на то, что все зависимые сущности $this->em->persist($entity). Я думал проблема в транзакции, закомментировал транзакцию, проблема не в ней. Проходит несколько циклов, распарсивается свободно несколько итераций, но как только выпадает какая либо ошибка БД, хоть по нарушению уникальности, хоть еще какая-либо, сразу после нее начинает сыпаться:

```
Multiple non-persisted new entities were found through the given association graph:

 * A new entity was found through the relationship 'ENTITY_NAME' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
 * ...
```

Сущности разные, по сути она падает на все зависимые сущности, участвующие в парсинге. Повторяю везде сделан persist и даже flush сущности, которые создавались или изменялись. Да после изменения они могли быть переданы в другую сущность. и это нормально. И самое главное всё это работает, пока не выскочит хоть какая-то ошибка БД. Хочется разобраться почему это вообще происходит

Comment: Да еще забыл добавить. Если убрать очистки и проверки на открытие соединения и создание его, то ошибка будет другая. По сути после первого исключения из базы будет сыпаться ошибка, что EntityManager is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ушло не мало времени чтобы найти более менее нормальный способ.

Как и писал в вопросе:

```php
    if (!$this->runParameters->entityManager->isOpen()) {
                    $this->runParameters->entityManager = $this->runParameters->entityManager->create(
                        $this->runParameters->entityManager->getConnection(),
                        $this->runParameters->entityManager->getConfiguration()
                    );
    }
```

Этот способ восстановления соединения не работает и только пораждает проблемы с зависимостями. Не знаю почему все пишут использовать его, может на простых сущностях и все нормально, но на сущностях с большим числом зависимостей этот способ не работает.

А решение следующее! Если это команда, как в моем случае, то через `$this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine');` можно запросить контейнер доктрины. Этот контейнер я записал тоже в параметры запуска, это не красиво, но это лучше чем передавать его через цепочку методов. Далее там где был отлов ошибки, где соединение завершает работу я сделал:

```php
try {
                $parser = new Parser\Wrapper($item, $this->runParameters);
                $countOffers += $parser->parse();
                $this->runParameters->entityManager->commit();
            } catch (\Throwable $t) {
                $this->runParameters->entityManager->rollback();
                $this->runParameters->logger->error('Failed parsed offer', [
                    'code' => $t->getCode(),
                    'message' => $t->getMessage(),
                    'file' => $t->getFile(),
                    'line' => $t->getLine(),
                    'trace' => $t->getTraceAsString(),
                ]);
                $this->runParameters->entityManager->clear(); //Чистить не обязательно, оставил в качестве эксперимента
                $this->runParameters->entityManager->close(); //Закрываем соединение, если вдруг там еще что-то случилось  оно вдруг не закрылось.
                $this->runParameters->doctrine->resetManager(); //Делаем reset из того самого контейнера
            }
```

В таком случае все последующие итерации начинают работать даже после падения и вылета ошибки из БД, и при этом не нарушаются зависимости.

Решение мне не очень нравится, но мне и не нравится то, что доктрина закрывает соединение после ошибки из бд. И в модели запрос-ответ это отличное решение, но для парсинга чужеродных сущностей всех ошибок не отловишь, поэтому просто необходимо продолжать парсинг, а "кривые" сущности просто пропускать и вести лог о них.